# how to get dateformat to capitalize month and day

Tags: java, date, capitalize

I have my strings like so in my strings.xml:

```
<string name="day_format">EEEE</string>
<string name="date_format">dd. MMMM</string>
<string name="date_format_us">MMMM dd</string>
```

And I use them like this in the code:

```
    private void reinit() {
    mDayFormat = getString(R.string.day_format);
    if (!DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this))
    {
    mDateFormat = getString(R.string.date_format_us);
    }
    else {
        mDateFormat = getString(R.string.date_format);
    }
    mTimeFormat = is24HourMode(this) ? FORMAT_24_HOURS : FORMAT_12_HOURS;
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
}
```

But it displays the day and the month in lowercase, and I want it to capitalize both. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it like so:

```
        final CharSequence date = DateFormat.format(mDateFormat, mCalendar);
    final CharSequence day = DateFormat.format(mDayFormat, mCalendar);
    String time = (String) DateFormat.format(mTimeFormat, mCalendar);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.clock2by2);
    String days = new String(day.toString().substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + day.toString().substring(1));
    String dates = new String(date.toString().substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + date.toString().substring(1));

    views.setTextViewText(R.id.Day, days);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.Date, dates);
    views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.TimeView, buildUpdate(time));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`WordUtils.capitalize(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29) from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) (on the result string)

(this is in case you want to capitalize - i.e. uppercase only the first letter. Otherwise you can simpyl use `.toUpperCase()`)

Update: Since it appears this is android, you can open the sources of `WordUtils` and copy the implementation from there, rather than getting the whole library.

Comment: +1, but I don't think it's worth to just include the commons jar into the Android app just because of one function. toUpperCase() should be fine; even if you just want the first letter to be capitalized, just use a helper method if you don't need anything else from commons.

Comment: I missed the android there. (The `R` is the only thing to hint in that direction)

Answer (score 2):

`String's toUpperCase()` ?

Answer (score 2):

There are more precise way of doing this. You can control each part of your formatter using DateFormatSymbols.

Look at that, this is beautiful:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatTo = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");

DateFormatSymbols dateFormatSymbols = new DateFormatSymbols();
String[] months = simpleDateFormatTo.getDateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths();
for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
    months[i] = months[i].toUpperCase();
}
dateFormatSymbols.setShortMonths(months);
simpleDateFormatTo.setDateFormatSymbols(dateFormatSymbols);

Date date = simpleDateFormatFrom.parse(s.next());
System.out.println(simpleDateFormatTo.format(date));
```